# i want to find the last date in 2 year

Tags: mysql, sql

Can any one tell me the query to find the last date in 2 year?

I have 1 table nominate: transaction
inside that I have 4 colunms:

- receiptnumber
- receiptdate
- price
- account

I want to find the last receiptdate for account

thanks all

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? They have their own different date/time handling features. (Non-ANSI SQL...)

Comment: You write "Last data in 2 year". Does that mean last date, or last date some specific year?

Comment: i use MySQL.JARLH and i want find the last date in 2 year. for example i have 3 date one is 15/01/2013 two is 15/01/2014 three 15/02/2014 i wana see 15/02/2014 if the receiptdate  is 14/01/2016 i wana see this date. the last date in 2 years from today

Comment: Simply use ``MAX``. e.g. ``SELECT MAX(receiptdate) FROM nominate;``

Comment: And if you also have 15/01/2012 and 15/01/2015?

Comment: my tutor sad the max is wrong, i must use dateadd function with case function

Comment: `Case` is not a function, it's an expression. (Tell your tutor.)

Comment: jarlh if have 15/01/2012 and 15/01/2015 i want see 15/01/2015

Comment: my falt sorry i'm a junior

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding you.. look at my answer, tell me whats wrong there and maybe I'll understand

Comment: I still don't get it how the two-year thing comes into play. Are you saying you want the last date per account, but if that date is more than two years ago, then don't show it? If so, would you show the account without a date then or would you want to remove the account from your result list?

Comment: And you want to find the last receipt date per account only? You don't need to find the related price and receipt number?

Comment: only lastdate in 2 years

Comment: What does this mean exactly? Show the last date per account, but show only accounts where the last date is not older than two years?

Comment: my table is wrong, is a test table, my tutor have a product table, in the product table, i wana see  when the client bought the last purchase, in the years. if a customer buys a lot or not

Comment: It's just a bit hard to understand :-) So you want to show *all* accounts and for each you want to show either 'bought this year', 'bought last year' or 'not bought within this and last year'? If the task is like that, then suddenly your teacher's advice to use `CASE WHEN` makes sense.

Comment: COMPLETELY RIGHT, MY TUTOR TELL ME USE CASE WHEN, BUT I NEVER USE CASE WHEN

Comment: For every Accout i wana see: the first purchase, the last purchase, the last purchase in 24 month, the last purchase in 12 month,

Comment: can you tell me how i can do this exercise with CASE WHEN? thank a  lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you finally told us the real task

> For every Accout i wana see: the first purchase, the last purchase,
>   the last purchase in 24 month, the last purchase in 12 month

the task is quite different. I assume that with "purchase" you still mean the date only.

Here is the query, you take min and max date plus max for 12 and 24 months:

```
select 
  account__c, 
  min(datascontrino__c) as primoscontrino,
  max(datascontrino__c) as ultimoscontrino,
  max(case when datascontrino__c > curdate() - interval 2 year then datascontrino__c end)
    as ultimoscontrino24mesi,
  max(case when datascontrino__c > curdate() - interval 1 year then datascontrino__c end) 
    as ultimoscontrino12mesi
from transazione__c 
group by account__c;
```

Comment: you're the best thorsten, very patient and  
helpful thanks